# C# Editing a text file

Tags: c#, file, text

I have a single text file that I am trying to edit. Basically the text file holds data for a request in a business. So it'll store the name, employee ID, request type, request total, request status, and the date and time in that order. I have to be able to edit the total amount for a selected line. I'm using a list view to be able to select the item. So for example I have to take Smith's request, and edit the $2.00 and change it to let's say $4.00.

> Ryan Rock ,345 ,Food ,$456.00 ,Pending ,4/2/2015 3:48:45 PM
>
> Smith ,4567 ,Food ,$2.00 ,Pending ,4/2/2015 6:26:37 PM
>
> Jerry ,444 ,Travel ,$22.00 ,Pending ,4/2/2015 6:26:47 PM

```
private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            if (item.Selected)
            {                    
                string selected = item.Text.ToString();
                string str;

                double total;
                bool totalCheck = double.TryParse(txtTotal.Text, out total);

                    if (totalCheck)
                    {
                        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("../../textFile/ExpenseReportingData.txt");
                        lines[3] = "7";
                        File.WriteAllLines("../../textFile/ExpenseReportingData.txt", lines);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Ammount", "Error");
                    }                    
            }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hmm part of my code wasn't included in the coding box. not sure why but its posted above. Sorry if I seem like such a noob. I'm in my first c# class.

Comment: wait, its in there now. so all my code for this is in the box. sorry again.

Comment: I fixed your code block, the first line have to be indented by 4 spaces. I also used a quote block for your file structure. If you have troubles with your formatting, you can edit your question with the 'edit' link below the tags under your question. If you need more help for formatting, here's the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to edit a value on a specific line u could do something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] lineData = lines[i].Split(',');//split the line into an array ["Smith" ,"4567" ,"Food" ,"$2.00" ,"Pending" ,"4/2/2015 6:26:37 PM"]
            if (lineData[0] == "Smith")//0 is the index of the client name
            {
                lineData[3] = "$4.00";//modifie the value
                lines[i] = String.Join(",", lineData);
                File.WriteAllLines("../../textFile/ExpenseReportingData.txt", lines);
            }
        }
```

but I wouldn't recommend it , you should use a database to hold your data and each client has to have an unique id (many clients can have the same name this would create issues)

or you can try to use a XMl / JSON type of formatting as your text file

Comment: thank you for your help. This got the job done after a few changes so I could modify it via a text box. This should work perfectly since it's a beginner's course but I'll keep the database suggestion in mind for future projects.